# Can't read/write from/to anonymous pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, multiprocessing, anonymous-pipes

I am making a programm for my University project and having some troubles.
i have a process called "Server" that is starting some other processes called "clients". the Server process can read and write from a file. The client processes can ask the server for a certain article in the file and then modify or read it.

i create a anonymous pipe to share articles between the Server and the clients and putting it write and read handle into the command line of every client, so it can write and read to the pipe.

The problem is i can not read information from the pipe.
Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct clientData {
    HANDLE client;
    int operation;
    int studentNum;
};
struct Student
{
    int num;             
    string name;     
    double grade;       
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Student& item){
        out.write((char*)&item, sizeof Student);
        return out;
    }
};
struct serverData {
    HANDLE client;
    Student stud;
};
void main() {
    cout << "Enter the amount of students you want to input" << endl;
    int count;
    cin >> count;
    Student* students = new Student[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the num, name and grade for the " << i + 1 << ". student" << endl;
        cin >> students[i].num >> students[i].name >> students[i].grade;
    }
    ofstream outb("MyFile", iostream::binary);
    cout << "your binary file looks like" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        outb << students[i];
        cout << students[i];
    }
    cout <<endl  << "Enter the amount of clients" << endl;
    int processcount;
    cin >> processcount;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piApp;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    HANDLE  writepipe, readpipe, pipehandle, writtenClient,writtenserver,  dataready, mutex;
    writtenserver = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"writtenServer");
    dataready = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"dataready");
    CreatePipe(&readpipe, &writepipe, NULL, (sizeof HANDLE + sizeof Student));
    writtenClient = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"writtenClient");
    for (int i = 0; i < processcount; i++)
    {
        CreateProcess(L"client\\Debug\\client.exe",(LPWSTR)(string(" ") + (char*)&writepipe + string(" ") + (char*)&readpipe).c_str() , NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &piApp);
    }
    clientData item;
    serverData serv;
    DWORD bytesRead;
    int num;
    mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, L"currentClient");
    while (true) {
        WaitForSingleObject(writtenClient, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
        ReadFile(readpipe, (LPVOID)&item, sizeof clientData, NULL, NULL);
        num = item.operation;
        cout << " num" << endl;
        switch (item.operation) {
            case 1:{
                for (int i = 0; i < processcount; i++) {
                    if (students[i].num == item.studentNum) {
                        serv.client = item.client;
                        serv.stud = students[i];
                        WriteFile(writepipe, (LPCVOID)&serv, sizeof clientData, NULL, NULL);
                        SetEvent(writtenserver);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                WaitForSingleObject(dataready, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
                ReadFile(readpipe, (LPVOID)&serv, sizeof serverData, NULL, NULL);
                ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{}//Not Ready yet, i need to get the 1 working first
            default: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << students[i];
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct clientData {
    HANDLE client;
    int operation;
    int studentNum;
};
struct Student
{
    int num;               
    string name;     
    double grade;         
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Student& item) {
        out.write((char*)&item, sizeof Student);
        return out;
    }
};
struct serverData {
    HANDLE client;
    Student stud;
};
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "started" << endl;
    system("pause");
    HANDLE clientHandle, writepipe, writtenClient, writtenServer, readpipe, dataready, mutex;
    clientData item;
    writtenClient = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"writtenClient");
    writtenServer = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"writtenServer");
    item.client = GetCurrentProcess();
    clientHandle = GetCurrentProcess();
    writepipe = (void*)(argv[1]);
    readpipe = (void*)(argv[2]);
    dataready = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"dataready");
    mutex = OpenMutex(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"currentClient");
    int n = 0;
    DWORD bytesRead;
    serverData serv;
    while (n != 3) {
        cout << "Enter 1 to modify, 2 to read and 3 to exit" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        switch (n) {
        case 1: {
                WaitForSingleObject(mutex, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
                item.operation = 1;
                cout << "Enter the key to the studen(num)" << endl;
                cin >> item.studentNum;
                WriteFile(writepipe, (LPCVOID)&item, sizeof clientData, NULL, NULL);
                SetEvent(writtenClient);
                while (true) {
                    WaitForSingleObject(writtenServer, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER);
                    cout << "1 ";
                    ReadFile(readpipe, (LPVOID)&serv, sizeof serverData, NULL, NULL);
                    if (serv.client == clientHandle) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cout << serv.stud.name << endl << serv.stud.grade << endl << serv.stud.num << endl;
                cout << "Enter the students name and grade to modify" << endl;
                cin >> serv.stud.name >> serv.stud.grade;
                WriteFile(writepipe, (LPCVOID)&serv, sizeof clientData, NULL, NULL);
                SetEvent(dataready);
                break; 
            }
            case 2: { //I have to get 1 working first
                cout << "Enter the key to the studen(num)" << endl;
                cin >> item.studentNum;
                WriteFile(writepipe, (LPCVOID)&item, sizeof clientData, NULL, NULL);
                SetEvent(writtenClient);
                while (true) {
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                cout << "Exitting..." << endl;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                cout << "Wrong input" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I Understand that this is a big amount of code, but everything here is useful to debug the program. If u have any suggestions how to make it more beautiful write a comment, i will fix that.

Comment: You should add some error handling to your code.

Comment: you create pipes not inherited. and in call to `CreateProcess` you set `bInheritHandles` to *FALSE* - as result  `writepipe` and `readpipe` is only valid in context of parent (server) process,but not copied to child(client). and you pass not handle values to child (which in this case senseless) but even address of local variables - `&writepipe` and `&readpipe` - that at all absolute senseless. so in child process - `writepipe = (void*)(argv[1]);` and `readpipe = (void*)(argv[2]);`- this is not a handles, but trash. if you check result of `WriteFile` or `ReadFile` - you got false

Comment: with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`

Comment: and about pipes. for my look instead of use `CreatePipe` and have  separate pipe handles for read and write (2 in parent and 2 in child) - much more better use one common pipe handle for both read and write - use `CreateNamedPipe` (not inherited handle, use in parent) + `CreateFile` (inherited handle, copied to child, close in parent)

Comment: @RbMm HANDLE has type void*, and (HANDLE)atoi(argv[1]) or (HANDLE)atol(argv[1]) is not working. How can i fix that?
I have to do that with anonymous pipes, because my Lector told me to do this that way.

Comment: at first fix your mistake with inheritances. about how pass pipe to child process - why not use `STARTUPINFO` ? about `my Lector told` - this is your problems, but I prefer to defend my opinion reasonably and not blindly follow all instructions. here problem in `CreatePipe` function, which is very bad design (not let set pipes access and attributes)

Comment: You need to convert the handle values into a string containing a number, and then in the child convert the string containing a number back into a handle value.  You can't do that by casting, you need to call an actual function.  If you *must* use anonymous pipes, you can make them inheritable by calling SetHandleinformation.  You should use two pipes, one for sending data from the parent to the child and one for sending data from the child to the parent.  (Using a single anonymous pipe could be made to work in principle, but it is an unnecessary complication.)

Comment: See [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx) on MSDN.